# joomla 3 trigger a function upon publish in component

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am working on updating an existing Joomla plugin.  It runs on the admin side and imports articles as drafts.  I need to send a trackback link when the content is published. How do I tell Joomla to call one of my functions when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and listen to the onContentAfterSave event (a Joomla content plugin event).
This is the description from the Joomla site:

> This is an event that is called after the content is saved into the database. Even though article object is passed by reference, changes will not be saved since storing data into database phase is past. An example use case would be redirecting user to the appropriate place after saving.